# ERROR: argument of type "" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi, wchar

I know this has *probably* been asked before, but I am in need of a fix. I have tried to alter it, but yet again this error keeps popping up.

```C++
// Get the dll's full path name
    char buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetFullPathName(L"Project1.dll", MAX_PATH, buf, NULL);
    printf(buf);
    printf("\n");
```

If any of you could help me, I would appreciate it heavily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `L"Project1.dll"` ? What type is it?

Comment: Error is Argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter type LPWSTR

Comment: The project is a console application, why?

Comment: Please add your error message.

Comment: The error message could hardly be clearer. Did you even read it? I find that a lot of beginners simply ignore error messages assuming that they won't understand them. It is a crippling state of affairs. Your real problem here is not that your code did not compile, rather that you have not learnt how to read and understand error messages. That should be the focus of your learning.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
char buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
```

With

```
WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
```

You're obviously calling a wide string version of `GetFullPathName` here, and your first argument is `wchar_t*`, so the buffer should be, too.

Or better yet, use `TCHAR` and `_T("Project1.dll")` instead of `L"Project1.dll"`.

Comment: This worked, Thank you so much. But it lead to another error on                    // Inject our main dll
 if (!Inject(pID, buf)) //buf being the error, again >:( -argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Comment: @AzuLX: sounds like you need to learn C++ and WinAPI string types a bit better. First of all, learn to read and understand the compiler errors.

Comment: @Viotlet Giraffe Many thanks for the help. :)

Comment: *"Or better yet, use `TCHAR` and `_T("Project1.dll")` instead of `L"Project1.dll"`."* - This is borderline downvote-worthy. While technically correct, this is not the way to go. The real solution is to use `L"Project1.dll"` and explicitly call the Unicode version `GetFullPathNameW`. Unless you need to support Windows 95, of course.

Comment: @IInspectable: this is one real solution, and the one I use in all my projects, but not the only one.

Comment: What's special about this solution is, that it is the worst imaginable one. There is no supported Windows release that natively uses anything but UTF-16LE encoded Unicode strings, and there hasn't been for [almost 10 years](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=6519). Writing code for something that doesn't exist is not just useless. It also makes use of preprocessor macros for no reason. And if you get unlucky one day, and need to undefine those macros for some other code to compile, you'll wish you had used a more appropriate strategy in all your projects.

Comment: @IInspectable: that's why I use the approach you suggested in all my projects. But it's not the most generic one. Besides, undefining system macros doesn't sound like a good idea anyway.

Comment: When you're writing a C++/CLI wrapper, undefining system macros is a **very** common scenario. Your library wouldn't be able to export a symbol called `CreateWindow` if you didn't. Whether this is a good idea or not, it's a common scenario, and there aren't many alternatives (zero come to mind).

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't understand. There's no symbol `CreateWindow`, it's a macro. There are `CreateWindowA` and `CreateWindowW` symbols.

Comment: Exactly. And if you attempt to export a symbol named `CreateWindow`, it will be translated to either `CreateWindowA` or `CreateWindowW` by the preprocessor. That's why you need to undefined those macros, if you want exports with the same name (which is common for wrapper libraries).